# Merge UIView with UIImageView before grabbing a screenshot

Tags: iphone

I wish to combine the background (UIImageView) to the overlying UIView (MyView) and then take a screenshot of the merged image. I am using the code below, but the background completely covers my UIView... Any suggestion please?

```
UIImageView *ViewToBeAddedAsBackground = BackgroundImageView;    
ViewToBeAddedAsBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,770,410); 
[MyView addSubview:ViewToBeAddedAsBackground];    

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(MyView.frame.size);
[MyView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *MyView_IMAGE = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(MyView_IMAGE, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are adding `ViewToBeAddedAsBackground` as a `subView` of `yourView`, so it will normally cover it, what you should do is the opposite, add `yourView` as a subView of `ViewToBeAddedAsBackground`

And then

```
[insertSubview:ViewToBeAddedAsBackground.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

You could try the following, depending on your current view heirarcy it could work

```
[MyView.superview insertSubview:ViewToBeAddedAsBackground belowSubview:MyView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(MyView.frame.size);
[MyView.superview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out immediately after posting it. I solved the problem with     [MyView sendSubviewToBack:ViewToBeAddedAsBackground];
Thanks anyway.